# Is it possible to search taggable_friends in Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search the taggable friends by query(e.g. name).
Is it possible with to use `me/taggable_friends` or `/search` ?

Should I fetch all taggable_friends, and filter in local ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to search through the list with the API, the best way is to get the first batch and present it to the user. It will most likely include the friends he wants to tag. If not, let the user load the next batch of friends with the pagination strings in the result.